# split field a string in a linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I tried in different ways to accomplish this but I can make it work I have a class called `CampoConfiguracionVista` Defined like this

```
public class CampoConfiguracionVista
{
    public CampoConfiguracionVista() 
    { 

    }

    public int IDCampo { get; set; }
    public int IDConfiguracion { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public bool ValidationEspecial { get; set; }
    public bool Requerido { get; set; }
    public int IDTipodato { get; set; }
    public int? minimo { get; set; }
    public int? maximo { get; set; }
    public string[] valores { get; set; }
}
```

And I have linq where I have i field called `Valores` which contains an string value separate by `;` So What to I want to Accomplish it's split this field value into a string array I tried in this two ways :

**first: all in one linq**

```
    var query = (from T in db.ConfiguracionCampo
             where T.IDTipificacion == idTipificacion
             && T.Campo.Activo == true
             select new CampoConfiguracionVista()
             {
                 IDCampo = T.Campo.IDCampo,
                 IDTipodato = T.IDTipodato,
                 ValidationEspecial = T.ValidationEspecial,
                 minimo = T.minimo,
                 maximo = T.minimo,
                 Requerido = T.Requerido,
                 Nombre = T.Campo.Nombre,
                 valores = T.Valores.Split(';')
             }).ToList();
```

**Second: I think that the problem was the linq can't translate the split to sql so i made two linqs like this ***

```
var query = (from T in db.ConfiguracionCampo
                         where T.IDTipificacion == idTipificacion
                         && T.Campo.Activo == true
                         select T);

var camposConfigurados = (from D in query select D).Select(C => new CampoConfiguracionVista()
            {
                IDCampo = C.Campo.IDCampo,
                IDTipodato = C.IDTipodato,
                ValidationEspecial = C.ValidationEspecial,
                minimo = C.minimo,
                maximo = C.minimo,
                Requerido = C.Requerido,
                Nombre = C.Campo.Nombre,
                valores = C.Valores.Split(';')
            }).ToList();
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Might be a typo, but in your description you say the string is split by semicolons `;` but in the code you're splitting by commas `,`.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for asking I check that and the error still remains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, some things you can't do with LINQ to SQL (an [example is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299979/string-split-in-a-linq-to-sql-query)). To get round the problem you simply need to do the bits that aren't in LINQ to SQL, with LINQ to Objects, so you need to convert IQueryable to IEnumerable, using something like [AsEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

If you force the data into memory *before* running the select by calling `AsEnumerable()`, I think your query should run fine.

```
var camposConfigurados = (from D in query select D)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(C => new CampoConfiguracionVista()
        {
            IDCampo = C.Campo.IDCampo,
            IDTipodato = C.IDTipodato,
            ValidationEspecial = C.ValidationEspecial,
            minimo = C.minimo,
            maximo = C.minimo,
            Requerido = C.Requerido,
            Nombre = C.Campo.Nombre,
            valores = C.Valores.Split(',')
        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are splitting by `','` instead of `';'`.

---

The last query can be simplified like this

```
var camposConfigurados = query
    .AsEnumerable() // <== this makes succeeding queries run with LINQ-to-Objects.
    .Select(C => new CampoConfiguracionVista() { 
        IDCampo = C.Campo.IDCampo, 
        IDTipodato = C.IDTipodato, 
        ValidationEspecial = C.ValidationEspecial, 
        minimo = C.minimo, 
        maximo = C.minimo, 
        Requerido = C.Requerido, 
        Nombre = C.Campo.Nombre, 
        valores = C.Valores.Split(';') 
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Hi and thanks thanks but I check, and the error still remains, i already modified the error in my question

Comment: I added a `.AsEnumerable()`. This separates the LINQ-to-SQL part from the LINQ-to-Objects part.