# Using LINQ to determine if a value exists in a DB table

Tags: sql, linq

I have a SQL table which has a simple string field that may contain a single value (like 'ABC' for example) or it may contain a list delimited by the pipe ('|') character (like 'ABC|EDF|GHI' for example).

If I have a SharePoint list and want to cross check to make sure that all of the values in my SP list exist in the SQL table, I can easily do it assuming the SQL field only has a single value:

```
var listitems = from SPListItem item in spList.Items 
                where item[myfieldname].Equals(valueImChecking) 
                select item;
```

How do I use a similar approach to check the same SQL field assuming it contains list of value delimited by '|'? If this field's value is 'ABC|EDF|GHI' and I'm checking if it contains 'GHI' for example, how do I build the query in LINQ?

TIA,
-Tony.

Comment: I think you need String.Split method. Unfortunately, it does not exist on Linq-to-SQL (see [split field a string in a linq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283752/split-field-a-string-in-a-linq)). So you may need to retrieve the data to the local computer memory (by converting `IQueryable` into `IEnumerable`) to process the field.

Comment: @Tony: Please look at comments by Cédric Bignon below my answer. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @shahkalpesh: yes, I believe so. Thanks.

Comment: @Tony: That means, my answer doesn't help. Right?

Answer (score 0):

```
var listitems = from SPListItem item in spList.Items 
                where item[myfieldname].ToString().Contains(valueImChecking) 
                select item;
```

[`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) method on string should help.

Comment: I tried 'Contains'but it doesn't work. The only 4 IntelliSense choices I get after [myfieldname] are:  </br> Equals    </br>  GetHashCode    </br> GetType    </br>  ToString

Comment: Does the code compile, leaving aside the intellisense not working? Have modified the answer to call `ToString` on the field value so that `Contains` can be performed.

Comment: Contains only work if all items in `item[myfieldname]` have the same size. Otherwise it can give wrong results.

Comment: @CédricBignon: Can you elaborate? I tried a sample with LINQ to SQL and it generates `LIKE` clause in the backend.

Comment: @shahkalpesh If `item[myfieldname]` can be `"ABC|WG|WXYZ"` and if you search for `"XYZ"`. Then the condition will pass. Even if it does not contain `"XYZ"` in the meaning of the list `"ABC", "WG", "WXYZ"`.

Comment: @CédricBignon: Yes, you are right. I think OP can answer that better, if that is what is required.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to split the values and write them to a separate table. I don't think it's a good design to store multiple values in the same field if you want to lookup them later.

If you don't want to change your database you can use shahkalpesh's answer. If however some values may contain other values (like `WXYZ` contains `XYZ`) this will only give you a list of possible candidates. You need to check the result in-memory:

```
// this filters for possible candidates
var candidates = from item in spList.Items 
                 where item[myfieldname].ToString().Contains(valueImChecking) 
                 select item;

// this filters the result using ling-to-objects
var listItems = from candidate in candidates.AsEnumerable()
                where candidate[myfieldname].ToString().Split('|').Contains(valueImChecking)
                select candidate;
```

Using `AsEnumerable` switches to Linq-To-Objects. This is required because LINQ to SQL does not support Split.

You can do some pre-filtering using the first query (which was taken from shahkalpesh's answer).
If your Items table is small it might also be a good idea to load everything into memory and do the check with ling-to-objects (using only the second query).