# split values separated by comma's in different lines

Tags: c#, sql-server

Hi I am trying to retrieve values from database. I have a row which has multiple image names separated by ",". I want to display them in different lines. I am using the following code which is working fine for two values. But even when I have three or more values then too it gives back only two. This is my query:

```
;with tmp(ImageURL,HeritageId) as
 (

select  LEFT(ImageURL, CHARINDEX(',',ImageURL+',')-1),
    STUFF(ImageURL, 1, CHARINDEX(',',ImageURL+','), '')
from shop.dbo.Images where HeritageId=@HeritageId
union all
select  right(ImageURL, CHARINDEX(',',ImageURL+',')-1),
    STUFF(ImageURL, 1, CHARINDEX(',',ImageURL+','), '')
from Images
where ImageURL > '' and HeritageId=@HeritageId
)
select  ImageURL
from tmp
```

Comment: Display on different lines *where*? In a WinForm, a web page, Management Studio, ... different programs expect different markup to show a carriage return + line feed.

Comment: Just to understand this correctly, your problem is that the SQL query doesn't return what you think it should? From your code sample it seems like you haven't gotten anywhere near displaying these results yet...

Comment: This code retrieves the data in separate lines. But works fine for only two images. if i have 3 or more images in the form :"a.png,b.png,c.png" then it doesnt work!! But if there are two images it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query looks like an attempt to use a recursive CTE to split a string. It that is the case it should look something like this.

```sql
;with tmp(ImageURL,Rest) as
 (

select  LEFT(ImageURL, CHARINDEX(',',ImageURL+',')-1),
    STUFF(ImageURL, 1, CHARINDEX(',',ImageURL+','), '')
from Images where HeritageId=@HeritageId
union all
select  LEFT(Rest, CHARINDEX(',',Rest+',')-1),
    STUFF(Rest, 1, CHARINDEX(',',Rest+','), '')
from tmp
where Rest > ''
)
select  ImageURL
from tmp
```

Use the CTE in the recursive part instead of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible/acceptable for you to retrieve them as one string and then use Split(',') to return an array of strings?

Alternately see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299979/string-split-in-a-linq-to-sql-query) question if you wish to use the LINQ-TO-SQL way.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using (and marking) the answer suggested by @Mikael, however if your sequence only has 4 values then you can use the `PARSENAME` function to split on a period.

```
DECLARE @test TABLE 
(
    [CSVColumn] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO @test VALUES ('The PARSENAME function splits on a period.But can only hold.Four.Values - any more and it will return null')
SELECT  PARSENAME([CSVColumn], 4) AS 'Col1', 
        PARSENAME([CSVColumn], 3) AS 'Col2', 
        PARSENAME([CSVColumn], 2) AS 'Col3', 
        PARSENAME([CSVColumn], 1) AS 'Col4'
FROM @test
```