# Scenario to split and create new row in Datatable?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a DataTable having 3 Columns. I want to perform a split operation on column 2 row value one by one and create new rows from the output of split. Is there any `Linq` method syntax for this senario?

```
{
    Col1    UserID          RNo
    ABC     FName1.SName1   10
    PQR     FName2.SName2   20
    XYZ     FName3.SName3   30

}
```

Desired Output

```
{
    Col1    UserID      RNo
    ABC     FName1      10
    ABC     SName1      10
    PQR     FName2      20
    PQR     SName2      20
    XYZ     FName3      30
    XYZ     SName3      30
}
```

Comment: You can probably feed a delegate to the `ForEach` function to do this. What have you tried so far?

Comment: It' already here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299979/string-split-in-a-linq-to-sql-query
And no you cannot, not every string function can be mapped to SQL.
But you can use it in LINQ to objects.

Comment: @Charleh I am new to Linq i tried using foreach loop First remove row and add row Datatable.

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you tried? You should be able to create the two rows then delete the original within a loop assuming you are OK with doing this on the client side (as Holger stated, this won't be easily translated in Linq to T-SQL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a helper method :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication137
{
    class Program
    {
        const string SPLIT_COLUMN = "UserID";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Col1", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("UserID", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("RNo", typeof(int));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"ABC", "FName1.SName1", 10});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"PQR", "FName2.SName2", 20});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"XYZ", "FName3.SName3", 30});

            DataTable dt2 = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .SelectMany(x => CloneRow(x, SPLIT_COLUMN)).CopyToDataTable();

        }
        public static  List<DataRow> CloneRow(DataRow row, string splitColumn)
        {
            DataTable dt = row.Table.Clone();

            foreach (string id in row.Field<string>(splitColumn).Split(new char[] { '.' }))
            {
                object[] newRow = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(x => (x.ColumnName == splitColumn) ? id : row[x.ColumnName] ).ToArray();
                dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
            }
            return dt.AsEnumerable().ToList();
        }


    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks @jdweng this works for me. I have one more question. How can we achieve this for dynamic columns in Datatable.For Ex: Col1,RNo there might be chances that datatable may have mob_No column or extra columns, And UserId will be present to perform split operation.

Comment: Data Columns can be index either by name or index number so you do not need the column name and can use the Count() to enumerate through the columns.  You can also use following : string[] columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(x => Column.Name).ToArray;

Comment: Instead of dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { row["Col1"], id , row["RNo"]}); I Used one more foreach loop
  DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                foreach (string CN in columnNames)
                {
                    if(CN != "Steps")                    
                        dr[CN] = row[CN];
                    else                    
                        dr[CN] = Steps; 
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dr); 

is there any better way in Linq?

Answer (score 3):

You can get your answer from here: **"[LINQ to separate column value of a row to different rows in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16354037/linq-to-separate-column-value-of-a-row-to-different-rows-in-net)"**

In your case, considering a User Class with three properties, your LINQ would be:

### LINQ Query

```
List<User> result = uList.SelectMany(item => item.UserId
                                       .Split('.')
                                       .Select(singleUserId => new User
                                       {
                                           Name = item.Name,
                                           UserId = singleUserId,
                                           RollNo = item.RollNo
                                       })).ToList();
```

### Output

```
Name    UserId  RollNo
ABC     FName1  10
ABC     SName1  10
PQR     FName2  20
PQR     SName2  20
XYZ     FName3  30
XYZ     SName3  30
```

I hope this helps..

Comment: This does not create a datatable like OP asked.